# How to change directory for $HOME

Tags: home-directory, environment-variables

My home folder (`~` and `$HOME`) points to `/home/user` , how do I change this directory?

I tried

```
HOME=/new/dir
```

But this only works until I start a new shell.

I also tried looking for definitions in `/etc/environment`, `~/.profile`, and `/etc/profile.d/` but I didn't find `HOME` defined anywhere.

I also looked [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving), but I'm not interested in moving it to a separate partition, I merely would like to change the directory it points to.

Answer (score 3):

`HOME` is usually derived from the user's entry in [`/etc/passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/passwd.5). You can use [`usermod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/usermod.8) to change this entry, but only if your user is not logged in. Therefore, you need to either:

1. Set a root password and login as root from a TTY, or
2. Boot to recovery mode (see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) for an example guide)

In either case, once you have a root shell, do:

```
usermod --move-home --home /path/to/new/home your-username
chown your-username:$(id -gn your-username) /path/to/new/home -R
```

This should move your home directory to the new location and ensure correct ownership (which the `usermod` command *should* do, the `chown` is just in case). Now logout/reboot and login as your user.

Answer (score 1):

To just change the home dir for the user USER to `/some/other/dir` use

```
sudo usermod --home /some/other/dir USER
```

You need to make sure `/some/other/dir` actually exists and has proper permissions. No files will be copied.

If you want to move the contents of the old home dir to the new one you can use.

```
sudo usermod --move-home --home /some/other/dir USER
```

Replace `/some/other/dir` with the path of the new home folder. If it doesn't exist yet it will be created. The content of the old $HOME will be moved to the new one.